# RequireJS is loading angular app, but doesn't create app.controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angularjs-controller

I've set up a very basic environment for loading AngularJS components (which are managed by Bower) using RequireJS.
My `index.html` is very basic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Resource Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
            <!-- this template is not populated -->
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="scripts/main"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My RequireJS is all in `main.js`, which looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'bower_components',
    paths: {
        'angular': '../bower_components/angular/angular',
        'angular-resource': '../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angular-resource': {
            deps: ['angular'],
        }
    },
});

define("app", ["angular", "angular-resource"], function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource']);
    return app;
});

require(["app"], function(app) {
    console.log(app); // this works
    app.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', '$resource',
        function($scope, $resource) {
            console.log("hello"); // this doesn't work
            $scope.items = [1, 3, 4, 5];
        }
    ]);
});
```

It seems that all dependencies are resolved and loaded, and the Angular app is being instantiated. However, I can't register the Angular controller.
The `console.log()` statement inside the callback function isn't executed, so it seems the controller creation fails completely?

/edit:

Adding a `ng-app` directive to `<body>` yields this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

[You can find the complete project on GitHub](https://github.com/doque/angular-requirejs), if that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of things that should/may be corrected in your code.

- Missing `angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);`. Because when you use requireJS, `angular.bootstrap()` is a need. Instead of angular got init right when script load, require got init first. And this it will cause your app crashed. In order to make it work you need to wait require init => then it will load angular up and init angular => after everything done, bootstrap your app.
- `define()` supposed to wrapped all code of a module/file
- `require()` Use to call a module/file.
- RequireJS use for seperating your modules into files. So it will be easier to management and possibly improve load time of your app if you config it nicely. By puting a many modules in a files. You just ruined the using purpose of requireJS. (e.g. I have built an app that got the total amount of code, plugins and html at around 3MB. But at the first page loading, it only 400kb, cool heh?)

You can try something like following:

```js
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'bower_components',
    paths: {
        'angular': '../bower_components/angular/angular',
        'angular-resource': '../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource',
        'app' : '../scripts/app' // 'app' is the module name. It got defined by define() block, and  can be loaded by either require() or define() block
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angular-resource': {
            deps: ['angular'],
        }
    },
});



require(["app"], function(app) {
    console.log(app);
    app.controller("MyCtrl", ['$scope', '$resource',
        function($scope, $resource) {
            console.log("hello"); // this doesn't work
            $scope.items = [1, 3, 4, 5];
        }
    ]);

    angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
});
```

and inside your app.js

```js
define(["angular", "angular-resource"], function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource']);
    return app;
});
```

Comment: Just edited a couple of typos and try to use better words for explaination.

Comment: I've change my file structure, as you suggested, but the behavior remains the exact same. See https://github.com/doque/angular-requirejs

Comment: @doque let me take a look on it

Comment: @doque okay I make a mistake. I will update the answer shortly. You just missing `angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);`.

Comment: This doesn't help, unfortunately. I've updated the code on GitHub.

Comment: it was work for me when I am using your code on github... okay I will give it a try on github then. EDIT: and I checked your code, you added it at the wrong place. Take a look at my answer again. If you just copy paste it in your project. It will work. And for using a module as controller. I suggesting you too take a look at **angularAMD**

Answer (score 0):

You have loaded angular, but you have yet to bootstrap it
since you load your scripts dynamically, using ng-app attribute is not an option
so you need to call

```
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

Comment: I've done that, but somehow `app` still isn't passed down to the controller. The error I'm receiving is `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`, which usually means that the module return value is incorrect. How can this be the case, though?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, i guess it has to do with that the controller is loaded before the app itself.. (trough the ng attribute?) so what should be the correct approach for the controllers part

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383540/requirejs-angular-doesnt-seem-to-register-controller-services-etc look at this example or use angularAMD here: http://plnkr.co/edit/azsKJnFJ0pYwBW0dGMFH?p=preview