# Angular js module won't load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get always the following error in angular js when I add `ng-app="adminApp"` to the body. The error is thrown during auto bootstrap.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module adminApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'adminApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

If I change it to only `ng-app` the error won't show up but i can't use `ngRoute` as it needs the app to be given a name. I read lots of solutions for this problem last 2 days but i found none of them working for me.

I removed everything and still won't work. I left only the ng-app and 3 elements.

index.html:

```js
window.mainmodule = angular.module('adminApp', ['ngRoute','ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
 </head>
 <body ng-app="adminApp">
  <div id="loadingscreen">
   <div style="left:0;top:0;width:0px;height:20px;background-color:#0000FF;" id="loadingbar"></div>
   <div class="center">Loading...</div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="utils/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="utils/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="utils/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="utils/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="utils/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="utils/require.js" data-main="modules/main"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I use angular v1.5.0-rc.0.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgwZLq

Comment: had you defined adminApp in your js? see an example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2

Comment: I think you forget to set external js file in your html page please check.
<script src""></script> there is no script tag except for angular plugin

Comment: I added the full code for you, also the modules/main.js. Later i want to add loading logic to modules/main.js. (I added it but the routing won't work as the module can't load.)

Comment: Can you share a codepen demo for us ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgwZLq Here you go. (backend?module=all gives all modules as json object, all modul has config function, that the routerprovider can run)

Comment: @androbin, Will you mind going through console of the provided codepen ?

Comment: @Rayon Dabre I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: @androbin, There are __14__ errors in the console(_ctrl+shift+j_)

Comment: Yes, there are, as the utils folder of my computer is not on codepen. It cannot find the files that i used. RequireJS and AnguarJS. Also the serverfiles. (I wrote what the files are meant for in a comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[original link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383540/requirejs-angular-doesnt-seem-to-register-controller-services-etc)

If you are using require.js, you need to programmatically bootstrap your angular application.

```
//kickoff the app
require(["app", "routes" ], function(){
   angular.module('adminApp', ['ngRoute','ngMaterial']);
   angular.bootstrap(document, ["adminApp"]);
});
```

When angular.js is loaded, it traverses the DOM and looks for "ng-app" to start the bootstrapping process. At that point of time your require.js dependency files hasn't been loaded on the page yet. So when angular tries to start the application and looks at your "adminApp", it doesn't exists yet. So, by deferring the bootstrapping, you'll have a chance the load your js files before angular goes out and bootstraps your app.

Remove `ng-app` tag from html. It will be added during bootstraping.

Comment: I edited your answer as the way I could solve the problem to help others.